# Delegate Jenkins authentication to Oauth1.0 or Custom Security Realm

Tags: jenkins, oauth, jenkins-plugins

We have a legacy Identity Provider which only supports two authentication mechanisms:

1. Oauth 1.0.
2. A custom service I can call with a user and password and
   obtain a session token which then has to be placed in a custom
   header of every other call to the IdP —to get user info and such.

I’d like to know whether there’s any plugin that will allow configuring Jenkins to delegate authentication to such an IdP through either mechanism. I'm starting to look at the [Oauth Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/OAuth+Credentials), but it doesn't look like it'll do the trick.

> By itself, this library has no user visible changes, it is intended only to surface new extension points on top of which OAuth providers may surface their own OAuth2Credentials implementations.

If not, then what are my options here? I’m thinking of writing a plugin to implement one of these. Is there a good guide I can use? Or an existing plugin I should extend?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out —and just in case anyone else is wondering how to do this— the Oauth Credentials Plugin is not for delegating Jenkins authentication to an Oauth Identity Provider. It's for creating Jenkins credentials which can then be used by jobs.

At this point in time, there's no plugin which will allow you to delegate Jenkins authentication to an identity providier exposing the deprecated Oauth 1.0 spec. You'll have to implement your own. The right way to do this is to extend this class:

```
hudson.security.SecurityRealm
```

I started doing this by following the examples set by [Github's](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-oauth-plugin) and [Google's](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-login-plugin) Oauth 2.0 plugins. But these both take very different approaches to the same problem — which filled my head with questions. So I did some more research and found [this nice article](https://apachelog.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/building-a-jenkins-security-realm/) which explains the basics and also points to a [bare bones security realm](https://github.com/mig82/jenkins-security-example) example of how to do this. It helped me a lot. I hope it'll help others as well.